# Using splice with an array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, splice

I have an array of strings.

I want to ckhek if in the array there are strings of blanks only and remove them.

To this purpose I've written the following code that trims the blanks and should then delete the elemens with length = 0.

The trim works, the string of blanks are actually of 0 legth (I check this with the alert) but the elements are not removed from the array.

Of course, searchterms is the array.

```
for (var i=0;i<searchterms.length;i++)
        {       
        searchterms[i]=searchterms[i].trim();
        alert(searchterms[i]+" - "+searchterms[i].toString().length);
        if  (searchterms[i].toString().length = 0)
            {
            searchterms.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
```

The same happens if I use the following code instead:

```
for (var i=0;i<searchterms.length;i++)
        {       
        tempterm=searchterms[i].trim();
        alert(tempterm+" - "+tempterm.toString().length);
        if  (tempterm.toString().length = 0)
            {
            searchterms.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
if  (searchterms[i].toString().length = 0)
```

You are performing an assignment(**=**) in the if statement where it should be comparison(equality operator **==**) instead.

```
if  (searchterms[i].toString().length == 0)
```

Another problem is that `splice` modifies the original array. So the indexes of elements at each iteration will change if a blank element is encountered.

This can also be done in a more concise way using `Array.prototype.filter`

```
var searchTerms = ['asdf', '', 'ed', '   ', 'd##'];    
var newTerms = searchTerms.filter(function(e) {
    return e.trim().length !== 0;
});

console.log(newTerms);
```

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KnZqT/)**

Comment: I tried first the simpler solution, i.e using == instead of = (it was a silly mistake!) but I found an unexpected problem: the cycle did'nt work in presenc of more consecutive zero length element in the array.  I can't still figure why that happened, but I solved the problem in another way: I put a conditional within another loop that processes the array in order to ignore those unwanted elements.

Comment: BTW, I also realized that if you process a string with searchterms=srchstr.split(" ") and the string contains more consecutive blanks, the resulting array contains null elements instead of blanks as I believed; for example, the result from "william   shakespeare" is william,,,shakespeare NOT "william, , ,shakespeare", sot that there is no need to trim anything (as you may understand, I'm not a Javascript expert ...)

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = Array();
var k=0;

for (var i=0;i<searchterms.length;i++)
{       
         if((searchterms[i].trim())!="" && searchterms[i].length>0)
         {
           temp[k] = searchterms[i];
           k++;
         }

}
```

Temp will contain the new arrray

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var i = 0;
while (i < searchterms.length)
{
    if (searchterms[i].trim().length == 0) searchterms.splice(i, 1);
    i++;
}
```